# best practice for leaving a git branch

Tags: git

I checked out a branch for testing purposes(let's call it `Test`) to see if it would be easy to do something. After seeing that it wasn't a good idea I just want to drop the branch. Can I just `$ git checkout Development` and just forget all about `Test` branch? Or would it be better to delete the branch? should I `$ git reset head`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Changing branches

Change to your original branch and maybe clean up any remaining file that was ignored by version control. That's all. If you want to, you can also `git branch -D Test` (capital D to avoid warnings about unmerged branch) but from experience, you should probably wait some time before doing so because you might want to go back to it a later point. I often cleanup local branch only after I am *done* implementing a feature.

#### Cleaning up

Suppose you created `Test` and now you go back to `master`:

```
$ git checkout master
```

You may have untracked files in your directory:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        some_file

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

You can simply delete the file manually, or run git clean:

```
$ git clean -n # -n says dry-run
Would remove some_file
```

The above just shows what would `clean` do; to really do it, enter:

```
$ git clean -f
Removing some_file
```

#### GitHub / remote repository

All the above applies to a local clone of your repository. In case you need to delete a remote branch, you can either do it from the Web interface, or [Delete the branch from command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2003505/124319).

Comment: ok thanks! also, how do I clean the local version, I have the branch there in github, but, haven't merged it anywhere into a pre-existing branch

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
git branch -d <name of your branch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete local branch:

```
`git branch -D <branch_name>`
```

Delete remote branch:

```
`git push <remote_name> --delete <branch_name>`
```

usually the `<remote_name>` is `origin`.

And yes, I think if the branch won't be used in the future it should be deleted, especially if it is pushed to the remote server. Because it grows the size of the repository even for developers that haven't checkout-ed this specific branch.